# Clustering or Finding Similarities Among Portfolio Allocations

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, statistics, similarity

I am trying to cluster a set of portfolios with percentage allocations among Stock, Bond, Other, and Cash. I am not sure what's the best way to go about this because the variables are interdependent as they have to add up to 100. Should I be using just one-dimension (e.g. Stock allocation)? If so, how do I determine if there are groups that exist in those set of portfolios? If its better to use 3 (n-1) variables, what method(s) can best handle this? Essentially, I want to see if these portfolios got similar over time. If there other suggestions such as t-tests, ANOVA, etc. I am happy to hear them as well.

I have tried using basic clustering methods K-means, OPTICS, HDBSCAN but the results are not that intuitive. It could be because I am thinking about the problem incorrectly. Kernel Density Estimation, Jenks Natural Breaks, and Expectation Maximization are somewhat okay but I am not sure if these will allow us to definitively argue that the portfolio allocation are 'similar' or not.

Thank you!